# Evaluate $\frac{d}{dt}f(x_1(t), x_2(t), ..., x_n(t))$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am supposed to evaluate $\frac{d}{dt}f(x_1(t), x_2(t), ..., x_n(t))$, but I somehow do not get what exactly is being asked, because I do not see any further simplification of this expression.

Comment: Are you familiar with the chain rule? Would you know how to evaluate $\frac{d}{dt}f(x(t))$? What about $\frac{d}{dt}f(x_1(t),x_2(t))$?

Comment: Oh ok, if this is just about applying chain rule its fine, thanks.

Comment: Exactly as @AlexOrtiz mentioned, you must use the Chain Rule. Unless you know exactly what the functions $f$ and $x_i$ are, your answer will be purely symbolic.

Comment: Does this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3714878/multivariable-chain-rule-notation-clarification/3714904#3714904 helps?

Comment: @Carlo Technically speaking, any written answer is purely symbolic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

notice that:
$$\frac{d}{dt}f(x(t))=\frac{df}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}$$
and that:
$$df(x_1,x_2...x_n)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}dx_1+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}dx_2...\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}dx_n$$
so if we combine these two rules (chain rule and total derivative) we get:
$$\frac{df(x_1,x_2...x_n)}{dt}=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\frac{dx_i}{dt}$$