# Understanding the multidimensional chain rule

Tags: multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

I have some trouble in understanding the multidimensional chain rule. For differentiable functions $f,g$, defined by $f: U \to V$, $g:V\to\mathbb K^n$ where $U \subseteq \mathbb R^d$, $V \subseteq \mathbb R^\nu$ are open,

$$\Big(\mathrm D(g \circ f)\Big)(x)=\Big(\mathrm D g(f(x))\Big)\cdot\Big(\mathrm Df(x)\Big).$$

I have rather accepted this identity than understood it. I already saw some examples and understood the fact that I did not understand something completely. By differentiating a multidimensional function, one apparentely differentiates the components  separately and somehow adds everything? Unfortunately I don't know exactly how... any explanation would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Answered same question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3714878/multivariable-chain-rule-notation-clarification/3714904#3714904

Answer (score 2):

When talking about the differential of a multidimensional function in general, without a specific function and application in mind, it's better to forget about its components. It's tedious and obstructs the view on what the differential is: a linear map.

The definition of (total) differentiability of a function $f:U\longrightarrow\mathbb R^m$ where $U\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ is open is that $f$ is differentiable in $x_0\in U$ if there exists a linear map $L:\mathbb R^n\longrightarrow\mathbb R^m$ which approximates $f$ nicely near $x_0$. "Approximating $f$ nicely" is an informal way to say that the difference between the function $f(x)$ and its (affine) linear approximation $f(x_0)+L(x-x_0)$ becomes small as $x\to x_0$, and quickly so. In particular, quicker than $x$ goes to $x_0$, or framed differently, quicker than $x-x_0$ goes to $0$. This can be phrased mathematically in two equivalent ways:

1. $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-[f(x_0)+L(x-x_0)]}{\Vert x-x_0\Vert}=0.$
2. There exists a remainder function $R_f:U\longrightarrow\mathbb R^m$ such that $f(x)=f(x_0)+L(x-x_0)+R(x)$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}\frac{R_f(x)}{\Vert x-x_0\Vert}$.

In (1), this limit just says that $f(x)$ minus its linear approximation $f(x_0)+L(x-x_0)$ goes to $0$, and the $\Vert x-x_0\Vert$ in the denominator guarantees that it does so quicker than $x-x_0$. And then (2) is just a rephrasing, where the remainder $R_f$ is just the numerator of the fraction in (1). Notice that nowhere did I reference components of a function. Sure, $f$ has components, and we could find a matrix representation of the linear map $L$ with respect to the standard bases of $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R^m$ whose entries would be the partial derivatives of the components of $f$, but that's just a representation, and we could represent it completely differently if we changed bases. The only important part is that it's linear and has the properties described above. Anyway, we call this linear map $L$ the (total) differential of $f$ at $x_0$, and we like to write it as $\mathrm D f(x_0)$ to make sure that everyone knows which function it approximates and at what point. But it's still a linear map.

Now to the actual point of your question, we want to find the differential $\mathrm D(g\circ f)(x_0)$ of a composition of two differentiable functions $f:U\longrightarrow\mathbb R^m$ and $g:V\longrightarrow\mathbb R^l$, where $U\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ and $V\subseteq\mathbb R^m$ are open and $f(U)\subseteq V$. Since $g\circ f$ is a function $U\longrightarrow\mathbb R^l$ where $U\subseteq\mathbb R^m$, this differential is a linear map

$$\mathrm D(g\circ f)(x_0):\mathbb R^n\longrightarrow\mathbb R^l.$$

Note that this kinda fits the chain rule already: $\mathrm Df(x_0)$ is a map $\mathbb R^n\longrightarrow\mathbb R^m$, and $\mathrm Dg(f(x_0))$ is a map $\mathbb R^m\longrightarrow\mathbb R^l$. Applying $\mathrm Df(x_0)$ first and $\mathrm Dg(f(x_0))$ second will map from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^m$ and from there to $\mathbb R^l$, so in total, it maps from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^l$, just what we want. This is also the reason why the order matters for the multidimensional chain rule: The differential $\mathrm Df$ needs to be applied first, which is why it's on the right.

And the actual proof is just calculation: $f$ is differentiable in $x_0$ with differential $\mathrm Df(x_0)$ (I'll shorten this to just $L_f$ for the calculation), and $g$ is differentiable in $y_0:=f(x_0)$ with differential $\mathrm Dg(f(x_0))$ (shortened to $L_g$). Now according to the second version of the definition above, there exist remainder functions

$$\begin{align*}R_f:&U\longrightarrow\mathbb R^m,\\
R_g:&V\longrightarrow\mathbb R^l
\end{align*}$$

such that

$$\begin{align}f(x)&=f(x_0)+L_f(x-x_0)+R_f(x)&&(1)\\
g(y)&=g(y_0)+L_g(y-y_0)+R_g(y)&&(2)
\end{align}$$

and

$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{R_f(x)}{\Vert x-x_0\Vert}&=0,\\
\lim_{y\to y_0}\frac{R_g(y)}{\Vert y-y_0\Vert}&=0.
\end{align}$$

Now if we insert $y=f(x)$ in $(2)$ and remember $y_0=f(x_0)$, we get

$$\begin{align}g(f(x))&=g(f(x_0))+L_g(L_f(x-x_0)+R_f(x))+R_g(f(x))\\
&=g(f(x_0))+\underbrace{L_g(L_f(x-x_0))}_{=\mathrm Dg(f(x_0))\cdot\mathrm Df(x_0)(x-x_0)}+\underbrace{L_g(R_f(x))+R_g(f(x))}_{=R_{g\circ f}(x)}.
\end{align}$$

You can show that the rightmost part goes to $0$ even when divided by $\Vert x-x_0\Vert$, and then this equation is exactly what defines the differential of $\mathrm D(g\circ f)(x_0)$, and it is apparently $\mathrm Dg(f(x_0))\cdot\mathrm Df(x_0)$. The $\cdot$ is there to denote matrix multiplication because when actually calculating stuff we will use the matrix representation, but we could have written $\mathrm Dg(f(x_0))\circ\mathrm Df(x_0)$ just as well.

Comment: Thank you! Now I really got the idea. But I still don‘t know how I use it... the point with the sums must appear in the matrix product but I cannot connect the two concepts. Given a function $f: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^4, (x,y,z) \mapsto (x^3, y^3, z^3, x^2 y^2 z^2)$, how can I calculate $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(8x^7, 10y, z)$?

Comment: @Thomas: You define the function $g:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3,~(x,y,z)\mapsto(8x^7,10y,z)$ and then calculate $\mathrm D(f\circ g)$ according to the chain rule. The first column of its matrix representation will contain the partial derivatives of the component functions of $f$ w.r.t. $x$.

Comment: Okay - I just did it in general. By matrix multiplication, I worked out the following formula: $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}((g \circ f)_1(x)) = \sum_{j=1}^\nu \frac{\partial g_1}{\partial x_j}(f(x)) \frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_1}(x)$. Is it correct?

Comment: @Thomas: It should be $\mathrm Dg(f(x))\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(x)$, if I didn't miscalculate.

Comment: I noticed a mistake just a few seconds after I posted it - I edited $(g \circ f)$ to $(g \circ f)_1$, the first component. More general, would it be this? $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}((g \circ f)_k) = \sum_{j=1}^\nu \frac{\partial g_k}{\partial x_j}(f(x)) \frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i}(x)$

Comment: I think I got it nearly - but how can I interpret it as a generalization of the one-dimensional chain rule? That should be something like "apply the one-dimensional chain rule on each component of sth and for each component of sth other, add the whole thing together", shouldn't it?

Comment: If you really only want the partial derivatives of the components of $f\circ g$, you can just find those components explicitly and calculate their partial derivatives using the 1d chain rule.

Comment: I think I misunderstood something. Of course, I want to differentiate $f \circ g$ as a whole?

Comment: Then why are writing $\partial/\partial x_1$?

Comment: Oh, if you mean this - yes. I want to differentiate $f \circ g$ by $x_1$. Did I misunderstand you?

Comment: So you want the partial derivative of the function $f\circ g:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^4$ with respect to the first variable. For this you can just write $f\circ g(x)=(f_1(g(x)),\dots,f_4(g(x)))$ and notice that all four components are real valued functions of $\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R$. So you can just take their partial derivatives with respect to the first variable.

Comment: @ATW what you wrote $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}((g \circ f)_k)(x) = \sum_{j=1}^\nu \frac{\partial g_k}{\partial x_j}(f(x)) \frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i}(x)$ is certainly correct, though the notation is not the best because of the repeated use of $x_i, x_j$. It is perhaps better to write it as $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}((g \circ f)_k)(x) = \sum_{j=1}^\nu \frac{\partial g_k}{\partial y_j}(f(x)) \frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i}(x)$; just introduce a new letter $y$, so as to not confuse it with the $x$, or just write $D_i[(g\circ f)_k](x) = \sum_{j=1}^\nu D_jg_k(f(x)) \cdot D_if_j(x)$

Comment: Now I got it @Vercassivelaunos - of course, I can differentiate separately. For example, when I have $h: \mathbb R^d \times \mathbb R^\nu \to \mathbb R, g: \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R^\nu$ differentiable and $\varphi: \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R, x \mapsto h(x, g(x))$, then $\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x_1} (x) = \frac{\partial h}{\partial x_1} (x, g(x)) + \frac{\partial h}{\partial x_1}(x, g(x)) \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_1}(x)$?

Comment: No. The dimensions of the terms on the right side don't even match, so this can't be. When taking a partial derivative wrt $x_1$, you're essentially considering the function $i:x\mapsto (x,x_2,\dots,x_d)$, where $x_2,\dots, x_d$ are fixed, and then take the derivative of the function $\varphi\circ i$. You can do this by calculating the function explicitly and then just taking the 1d derivative, or you can use the chain rule like this: $\partial_{x_1}\varphi=\mathrm D(\varphi\circ i)=\mathrm D(\varphi)(i)\cdot\mathrm Di$. But then you need to calculate $\mathrm D\varphi$.